# passing useState to child

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to pass the useState values of my parent component to several children with the following code.

App.js

```
const [inSystem, setIn] = useState(false);
<Route exact path="/" functions={[inSystem, setIn]}  component={Loading} />
```

and then in my `loading` component I have

```
const [inSystem, setIn] = props.functions
<NavLink to="/sol">
          <button onClick={() => {setIn(true)}}>
            <p >Enter System</p> 
          </button>
        </NavLink>
```

This is a solution I found in response to a similar question, I have copied my solution [from this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-usestate-to-child-c0qx6?file=/src/Child.js). However I am receiving the following error:

> TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It may have to do with the fact that you are passing a list as a prop. I recommend that you pass the two different values and functions separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to pass arbitrary props to a route (I assume this is `react-router` v4 based on your syntax), but those props are being ignored. Try using `render` instead of `component`:

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/"
  render={(props) => {
    return (
      <Loading {...props} functions={[inSystem, setIn]} />
    );
  }}
/>
```

Comment: It looks like that was the issue. Thank you.